# what is Object Cloning in php?

Tags: php, object, clone

Can someone explain me

- what is Object Cloning in php?
- When should i use clone keyword in php?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Object cloning is the act of making a copy of an object. As [Cody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144506/what-is-object-cloning-in-php/2144523#2144523) pointed out, cloning in PHP is done by making a shallow copy of the object. This means that internal objects of the cloned object will **not** be cloned, unless you explicitly instruct the object to clone these internal objects too, by defining the magic method `__clone()`.

If you don't utilize the `__clone` method, the internal objects of the new object will be references to the same objecs in memory as the internal objects of the original object that was cloned.

Consider these examples:

```
// in this exampe the internal member $_internalObject of both objects
// reference the same instance of stdClass in memory.
class CloneableClass
{
    private $_internalObject;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // instantiate the internal member
        $this->_internalObject = new stdClass();
    }
}

$classA = new CloneableClass();
$classB = clone $classA;


// in this exampe the internal member $_internalObject of both objects
// DON'T reference the same instance of stdClass in memory, but are inividual instances
class CloneableClass
{
    private $_internalObject;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // instantiate the internal member
        $this->_internalObject = new stdClass();
    }

    // on clone, make a deep copy of this object by cloning internal member;
    public function __clone()
    {
        $this->_internalObject = clone $this->_internalObject;
    }
}

$classA = new CloneableClass();
$classB = clone $classA;
```

Use cases for cloning would for instance be a case where you don't want outside objects to mess with the internal state of an object.

Let's say you have a class User with a internal object Address.

```
class Address
{
    private $_street;
    private $_streetIndex;
    private $_city;
    // etc...

    public function __construct( $street, $streetIndex, $city /* etc.. */ )
    {
        /* assign to internal values */
    }
}

class User
{
    // will hold instance of Address
    private $_address;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_address = new Address( 'somestreet', '1', 'somecity' /* etc */ );
    }

    public function getAddress()
    {
        return clone $this->_address;
    }
}
```

For arguments sake, let's say you don't want outside objects to mess with the internal Address of User objects, but you do want to be able to give them a copy of the Address object. The above example illustrates this. The `getAddress` method returns a clone of the address object to calling objects. This means that if the calling object alters the Address object, the internal Address of User will not change. If you didn't give a clone, then the outside object **would** be able to alter the internal Address of User, because a reference is given by default, not a clone.

Hope this all makes some sense.

**PS.:**
Be aware though, that if Address would also have internal objects, you would have to make sure Address makes a deep copy of itself on cloning (as per my second example of this post) by defining `__clone()` in Address. Otherwise you will get headaches of trying to figure out why your data is screwed.

Answer (score 27):

Cloning is used to create a genuine copy of an object. Assigning an object to another variable does not create a copy - rather, it creates a reference to the same memory location as the object:

```
<?php

$o= new stdclass;
$o->a= 'b';
$o->b= 'c';

$o2= $o;
$o2->a= 'd';

var_dump($o);
var_dump($o2);

$o3= clone $o;
$o3->a= 'e';
var_dump($o);
var_dump($o3);

?>
```

This example code will output the following:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "d"
  ["b"]=>
  string(1) "c"
}
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "d"
  ["b"]=>
  string(1) "c"
}
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "d"
  ["b"]=>
  string(1) "c"
}
object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "e"
  ["b"]=>
  string(1) "c"
}
```

Comment: But why clone it instead of doing `$o2= new stdClass;` the modifying the properties like  `$o2->a= 'd';` is gives the same result right?

Comment: @samayo: No, it also does `$o3->b = $o->b`. Keep in mind leepowers wrote a simple example, but the benefit of having the same kind of object with all property's copied, that are afterwards reassignable without modifying the original object, is immense in more complex scenarios.

Answer (score 7):

Object Cloning, in terms of PHP 5, is what is known as a ["shallow copy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy). It then calls the __clone() method on the object being cloned.

Answer (score 6):

If you need a deep clone - that is, clones of the child objects and clones of the grandchild objects - you can either overwrite `__clone` in each of the classes, or simply serialize+unserialize the object:

```
function deepClone($object)
{
    return unserialize(serialize($object));
}
```

Comment: This is a great workaround. You save me hours of coding, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As explained in other answers, `clone` makes a **shallow copy** of the object.

If you need to make a **deep copy** (i.e. recursive copy), you can overload the `__clone()` methods.

You can also use this library: **[MyCLabs\DeepCopy](https://github.com/myclabs/DeepCopy)**, which is more simple and powerful than a simple clone.