# Clone PHP example usages

Tags: php, oop, clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is Object Cloning in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144506/what-is-object-cloning-in-php)

I am kind of new to Object oriented development, i am creating an application as an object oriented program, can you please provide me a few examples about how is normally used the clone method of PHP, real life examples preferred.

I would like to understand more fully the concepts related.

Thanks,

Comment: The documentation starts off with a few examples:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php  Is there something there you don't fully understand?

Comment: Is not that i do not understand what the manual says, but i don't see any issue for my actual level and i would like to know of a few examples to use in later implementations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is an example where I needed to clone an object the other day. I needed to have two DateTime objects, a `from date` and a `to date`. It was possible for them to be specified in URL arguments, however either could be omitted and I would need to set them to a default value.

*The example below has been simplified somewhat, so there are flaws in the implementation as it's presented below, however it should give you a decent idea.*

The problem lies in the DateTime::modify method. Lets assume the user has provided a *from* date, but **not** a *to* date. Because of this we set the *to* date to be 12 months from the given *from* date.

```
// create the from date from the URL parameters
$date_from = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_GET['from']);
```

The DateTime class features a method to modify itself by some offset. So one could assume the following would work.

```
$date_to = $date_from;
$date_to->modify('+12 months');
```

However, that would cause both `$date_from` and `$date_to` to be the same date, even though the example appears to copy the variable `$date_from` into `$date_to`, its actually creating a **reference** to it, not a copy. This means that when we call `$date_to->modify('+12 months')` its actually modifying both variables because they both point to the same instance of the DateTime object.

The correct way to do this would be

```
$date_to = clone $date_from; // $date_to now contains a clone (copy) of the DateTime instance $date_from
$date_to->modify('+12 months');
```

The clone statement tells PHP to create a new instance of the DateTime object and store it in `$date_to`. From there, calling modify will change only `$date_to` and `$date_from` will remain unchanged.