# When to clone objects in PHP?

Tags: php

All resources online have been on "**how to use**", but nothing describes "**when to use**". Of course some is by preference, So I would like to see answers to when would be a good time to use cloning on objects.

```
$object_2 = (clone) $object_1;
```

Now `$object_2` is a identical copy of `$object_1` and when they make changes, they are changed locally to their own objects instead of by reference of each other.

So what is the best strategy with cloning?

Comment: Hi. A good example described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2144675/4469537) .

Comment: Thanks @SergeyChizhik It makes perfect sense on the cloning, and of course the idea is so that no one can alter an object because its a copy and not a reference to it. But also realizing you'd need to call all the internal objects too.

Comment: You might do it manualy using magic `__clone`. This case described in [doc](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.cloning.php). It tells: When an object is cloned, PHP 5 will perform a shallow copy of all of the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other variables will remain references.